# Trying to get a simple webpack build using tailwind, getting unknown word error

Tags: npm, webpack, tailwind-css

I'm trying to get tailwindcss to work with webpack.

Currently I am getting the following error when running `npx webpack`:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError

(2:3) Unknown word

  1 | function hello(){
> 2 |   console.log('hi');
    |   ^
  3 | }
  4 |
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "blank",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \" no tests specified yo \" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^1.4.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "postcss": "^7.0.32",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      // ...
      use: [
        // ...
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            ident: 'postcss',
            plugins: [
              require('tailwindcss'),
              require('autoprefixer'),
            ],
          },
        },
      ],
    }],
  }
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

src/index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <p>hello</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

src/index.js

```js
function hello(){
  console.log('hi');
}
```

src/styles.css

```css
/* src/styles.css */

@tailwind base;

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;
```

Also, how can I reference the styles.css in my index.html file?  Do I have to grab it from the /dist folder once it is built?

Comment: You copied webpack.config.js from examples from this page [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/)
First, see how webpack works, because this file `// ...`
he didn't appear out of nowhere ;)
Below it can be used in this way `{ test: /\.css$/, use: [ { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { ident: 'postcss', plugins: [ require ('tailwindcss') require('autoprefixer') ] }}]}` Take a look at [webpack-boilprare](https://github.com/tomik23/webpack-boilerplate) you can attach tailwind to this

Comment: @GrzegorzT. I need an example that does both tailwind and also .js files...thanks!

Comment: Take a look here [tailwindWebpackPostCSS/](https://blog.konnor.site/javascript/tailwindWebpackPostCSS/) you have the whole example

Comment: I also have a question, what do you want to use tailwind for html or js? Because if only to the html itself then you can use without the webpack [tailwind-purgecss](https://github.com/tomik23/tailwind-purgecss)